# How do I sort through specific objects in an array using polymorphism?

Tags: java

I have this working code that outputs all the pets but how to iterate through it again and only print out the outdoor cats? In my case I only have an outdoor cat as the 3rd object(the one that has false in the 3rd argument).

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    Pet[] pets = new Pet[4];

    pets[0] = new Dog("Spot", 5, "bulldog");
    pets[1] = new Cat("Lucky", 1, true);
    pets[2] = new Cat("Kitty", 8, false);
    pets[3] = new Dog("Bud", 9, "great dane");

    Arrays.sort(pets);

    for(int i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(pets[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

}   

}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from...creating another `for`-loop that's *similar* to your first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the other answers, instanceof is a good way to determine the type of the object. But you also asked how to only print the outdoor cats. You mentioned the 3rd object "Kitty" was outdoor which suggests the false in the constructor is the "indoor" value.

Check each element for instanceof Cat. If this is true, this can be cast to Cat (you know it wont fail because instanceof Cat returned true) and then call your method which returns the indoor value. Here I'v used the ! operator to print the cat only is not indoor.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
        if (pets[i] instanceof Cat) {
            Cat cat = (Cat) pets[i];
            if (!cat.getIndoorStatus()) {
                System.out.println("Outdoor cat: " + cat);
            }
        }                
    }
```

Comment: I actually have getters and setters for that. Should that method replace it? I added the class into my question.

Comment: yes, just use whatever method returns the value. getIndoor() or whatever you have called it. doesn't matter what it's called as long as it returns the right value.

Comment: It should be `isIndoorStatus()`, not `getIndoorStatus()`. The JavaBeans pattern for getters and setters stipulates that getters that return a `boolean` should have a name starting with `is...`

Comment: Just for the record : the same way would be a method named isInDoor() for example. And then: using a boolean is also not an ideal choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the instanceOf operator.

```
for(int i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
    if (pets[i] instanceof Dog) {
        System.out.println(pets[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
    if(pets[i] instanceof Cat){
        Cat cat = (Cat) pets[i];
        if(!cat.outdoor){
          // print pets[i] here
        }
     }
}
```